# RestTemplate using to handle POST

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-3

I want to call a rest service in java code.My code as follows..

---

```
RestTemplate template = new RestTemplate();
TPOSBillDTO dto = new TPOSBillDTO();
dto.setId(1);

template.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter());
template.getMessageConverters().add(new StringHttpMessageConverter());
template.getMessageConverters().add(new FormHttpMessageConverter());

template.postForLocation("http://localhost:6458/games/toys",dto,String.class);
```

---

Below is my rest service

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/toys", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView toys(@RequestParam TPOSBillDTO dto){
        Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        System.out.println("Save Toy Details " + dto);

        return new ModelAndView("jsonView", model);
}
```

---

DTO class looks like this

```
public class TPOSBillDTO {

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private List<String> address;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public List<String> getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(List<String> address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

---

Im getting an Exception as follows... Help me to solve this issue...

Is this the correct way to call a POST service with parameters .. This is working fine when im not accepting any parameters to the POST service...

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.springframework.web.client.UnknownHttpStatusCodeException: Unknown
>   status code [311] 311     at
>   org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.getHttpStatusCode(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:58)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.hasError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:49)

Comment: 311 is a non-standard status code. Where in your application do you return that? If you don't know, please post your context configuration.

Answer (score 0):

dto is in body of request it is not send as a url parameter
you should use :

```
public ModelAndView toys(@RequestBody) TPOSBillDTO dto){
```

Comment: still having the same issue even i change to @RequestBody

Comment: can you pls try to debug you rest service. Put pls breakpoint on line System.out.println("Save Toy Details " + dto); so it is possible to distinguish where is the problem. thx

Comment: also can you pls try change return new ModelAndView("jsonView", model); to return new ModelAndView("jsonView"); so we can check that there is no problem with view resolver. model is empty map anyway. thx

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use "exchange" rather than "postForLocation"?
e.g.

```
template.exchange("http://localhost:6458/games/toys", dto, String.class);
```